# How does pipenv create Python.exe (Windows) and has this changed?

Tags: python, pipenv

I have a Python project that I have been working on for a few years. I have been using pipenv to ensure a consistent environment. I have earlier versions of the project saved and I have noticed a difference with regards to how Python.exe is created in the .virtualenv/project/Scripts folder. Previously Python.exe was copied together with Python3.dll and Python3(pythonversion).dll. When I have recreated the environment now there is a larger sized Python.exe in the Scripts folder and neither of Python3.dll and Python38.dll. The only difference that I am aware of is that I was using windows 10 earlier but am using windows 11 now.

1. How does pipenv create Python.exe in the .virutalenv/project/Scripts folder?
2. Has there been any change in CPython3Windows?
3. Is there anything else that could explain why the Python.exe is created differently?

I want pipenv to create Python.exe as it has done previously I have tried to install 5 different versions of pipenv but that did not resolve the issue. I have copied an old project where it had Python.exe + Python3.dll + Python38.dll but when I do pipenv install on that Pipfile I get the large Python.exe instead of the three files.

For me the change in how Python.exe is created creates a problem with my automatic tests but that is another issue.

/Mattias